# nvidia-xconfig issue: error retrieving symbol nvCfgIsPrimaryDevice from libnvidia-cfg.so.1

Tags: debian, x11, drivers, xorg, nvidia

I'm trying to setup my nvidia graphics card in Debian 11. To the best of my knowledge I've setup the drivers correctly, and have the following output for `nvidia-smi`:

```
Mon Mar 25 10:04:05 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.157                Driver Version: 390.157                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 675M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
|  0%   60C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  1985MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I understand correctly, this means I've got the drivers setup correctly, but I need to setup Xorg to use the graphics card now, which should be done with `nvidia-xconfig`.

When I run `nvidia-xconfig` however, I get this output:

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.


WARNING: Unable to parse X.Org version string.


WARNING: error retrieving symbol nvCfgIsPrimaryDevice from libnvidia-cfg.so.1:
         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.1: undefined symbol: nvCfgIsPrimaryDevice


ERROR: Unable to find any GPUs in the system.


ERROR: Unable to write to directory '/etc/X11'.
```

The last error is because I'm not running as `sudo`. When I run with `sudo` an xorg config is generated that does not cause the nvidia graphics card to be used.

I believe it cannot find my graphics card because of the previous symbol error:
`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.1: undefined symbol: nvCfgIsPrimaryDevice`

To my knowledge all the appropriate packages are installed (since the library does exist), but is the wrong version installed since the symbol is not there?

Not sure how to further diagnose this, any help is much appreciated!